# Zenject Unity3D testing scene hit "unable to resolve class" how to get rid of?

Tags: unity-game-engine, integration-testing, zenject

I have SceneA (A) and SceneB (B). The B has also a Foo AsSingle and NonLazy installed by the SceneContext Installer. The Foo has an IInitialize implemented to Debog.Log("Hello Errors!"):

```
yield return LoadScene("SceneA");
yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneB");
yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
var newSceneContainer = ProjectContext.Instance.Container.Resolve<SceneContextRegistry>()
.SceneContexts.Single().Container;
Foo foo = newSceneContainer.Resolve<Foo>();
```

And I guet "Unable to resolve the class", while in the debug I see the hello message of Foo, so the Installer has done its job. Now in case Foo is a MonoBehaviour, on a gameobject with Zeneject binding it as component "from the scene", then without problem it will be resolved.
Please kindly let me know how to resolve, in this case.
**-- Edit -- 1 **
Foo is renamed to "BClass".
A's Installer is empty.
B's Code:

```
public class BInstaller : MonoInstaller
{
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.BindInterfacesAndSelfTo<BClass>().AsSingle().NonLazy();
    }
}

public class BClass : IInitializable, IDisposable {
    public void Initialize() { Debug.Log("Hello Errors!"); }
    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

Finally the test:

```
public class ScenesFlow_A_to_B : SceneTestFixture
{
    [UnityTest]
    public IEnumerator TestScene()
    {
        yield return LoadScene("SceneA");
        //waiting
        SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneB");
        //waiting
        var newSceneContainer = ProjectContext.Instance.Container
        .Resolve<SceneContextRegistry>().SceneContexts.Single().Container;
        BClass bc = newSceneContainer.Resolve<BClass>() as BClass;
        Assert.IsNotNull(bc);// fail!
    }
}
```

**-- Edit 2 --**
New changes:

```
public class ScenesFlow_A_to_B : SceneTestFixture
{
    [UnityTest]
    public IEnumerator TestScene()
    {
        yield return LoadScene("SceneA");
        //SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneB");
        yield return SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("SceneB");
        var newSceneContainer = ProjectContext.Instance.Container
        .Resolve<SceneContextRegistry>().SceneContexts.Single().Container;
        BClass bc = newSceneContainer.Resolve<BClass>() as BClass;
        Assert.IsNotNull(bc);
    }
}
```

the result will be this:

```
TestScene (0.323s)
---
System.InvalidOperationException : Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
---
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[SceneContext] (IEnumerable`1 source) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at ScenesFlow_A_to_B+<TestScene>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00089] in ...  at UnityEngine.TestTools.TestEnumerator+<Execute>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00031] in .../TestEnumerator.cs:29
---
Loading scene 'SceneA' for testing
I am class B
```

Comment: How is Foo installed?  What is the binding statement?

Comment: Very sorry, I was tired last night and didn't publish the code.

Comment: Can you try `yield return SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync` instead?

Comment: Please have a look on Edit-2 above.